# d3 scaleLinear update and zoom conflict

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

i have a problem combining manual update and zoom functionality in d3.

Here is a small demo code cut off out of a larger module which creates only a linear scale.

https://jsfiddle.net/superkamil/x3v2yc7j/2

```
class LinearScale {
  constructor(element, options) {
    this.element = d3.select(element);
    this.options = options;

    this.scale = this._createScale();
    this.axis = this._createAxis();
    this.linearscale = this._create();
  }

  update(options) {
    this.options = Object.assign(this.options, options);

    this.scale = this._createScale();
    this.axis = this._createAxis();

    this.linearscale.call(this.axis);
  }

  _create() {
    const scale = this.element
    .append('g')
    .attr('class', 'linearscale')
    .call(this.axis);

    this.zoom = d3.zoom().on('zoom', () => this._zoomed());

    this.element.append('rect')
      .style('visibility', 'hidden')
      .style('width', this.options.width)
      .style('height', this.options.height)
      .attr('pointer-events', 'all')
      .call(this.zoom);

    return scale;
  }

  _createScale() {
    let range = this.options.width;

    this.scale = this.scale || d3.scaleLinear();

    this.scale.domain([
      this.options.from,
      this.options.to
    ]).range([0, range]);

    return this.scale;
  }

  _createAxis() {
    if (this.axis) {
      this.axis.scale(this.scale);
      return this.axis;
    }

    return d3.axisBottom(this.scale);
  }

  _zoomed() {     
    this.linearscale
      .call(this.axis.scale(d3.event.transform.rescaleX(this.scale)));

    let domain = this.axis.scale().domain();

    this.element.dispatch('zoomed', {
      detail: {
        from: domain[0],
        to: domain[1],
      },
    });
  }
}

const scale = new LinearScale(document.getElementById('axis'), {
  from: 0,
  to: 600,
  width: 600,
  height: 100
});

document.getElementById('set').addEventListener('click', () => {
  scale.update({
    from: 0,
    to: 100
  });
});
```

1. Zoom x axis out to 0 - 10000 (random numbers)
2. Click on the "set" button
3. X axis sets the domain from 0 - 100
4. Start zooming out again

-> Expected: Zoom starts from the domain 0 - 100

-> Result: Zoom jumps back to the previous zoom level 0 - 10000

I know, that d3 is working with a scale copy and i'm updating the original scale but i don't find a way how to combine them or how to set the zoom level to the original scale.

https://github.com/d3/d3-zoom/blob/master/README.md#transform_rescaleX

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: I got 0-100 when I pressed the "set" button.

Comment: the problem was later at "4. Start zooming out again". But it's fixed now. Look at Cosma's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either recreate the zoom behaviour or just reset the current zoom transforms.
You should be able to reset each parameter( zoom and translate) or just reset them all. The following example also triggers the zoom specific events, but as you already have the domain set it should not be a visual problem.

Ex: 
Add 
  this.element.select("rect").call(this.zoom.transform, d3.zoomIdentity);
in your update function.

More information regarding the zoom api in https://github.com/d3/d3-zoom/blob/master/README.md#zoom_transform . Also I found an example using a transition animation at https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/db6b4335bf1662b413e7968910104f0f .
I also updated the fiddle:

```
update(options) {

  this.options = Object.assign(this.options, options);
  this.scale = this._createScale();
  this.axis = this._createAxis();

  this.linearscale.call(this.axis);
  this.element.select("rect").call(this.zoom.transform, d3.zoomIdentity);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/x3v2yc7j/8/